# C# using the "this" keyword in this situation?

Tags: c#, oop, this

I've completed a OOP course assignment where I design and code a Complex Number class.  For extra credit, I can do the following:

1. Add two complex numbers. The function will take one complex number object as a parameter and return a complex number object. When adding two complex numbers, the real part of the calling object is added to the real part of the complex number object passed as a parameter, and the imaginary part of the calling object is added to the imaginary part of the complex number object passed as a parameter.
2. Subtract two complex numbers. The
   function will take one complex
   number object as a parameter and
   return a complex number object. When
   subtracting two complex numbers, the
   real part of the complex number
   object passed as a parameter is
   subtracted from the real part of the
   calling object, and the imaginary
   part of the complex number object
   passed as a parameter is subtracted
   from the imaginary part of the
   calling object.

I have coded this up, and I used the this keyword to denote the current instance of the class, the code for my add method is below, and my subtract method looks similar:

```
 public ComplexNumber Add(ComplexNumber c)
{
    double realPartAdder = c.GetRealPart();
    double complexPartAdder = c.GetComplexPart();

    double realPartCaller = this.GetRealPart();
    double complexPartCaller = this.GetComplexPart();

    double finalRealPart = realPartCaller + realPartAdder;
    double finalComplexPart = complexPartCaller + complexPartAdder;

    ComplexNumber summedComplex = new ComplexNumber(finalRealPart, finalComplexPart);

    return summedComplex;
}
```

***My question is:*** Did I do this correctly and with good style? (using the this keyword)?

Comment: +1 for asking a question about homework and showing that you've put a good effort in first, rather than just asking people on here to solve it for you. keep up the good work

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The use of the `this` keyword can be discussed, but it usually boils down to personal taste. In this case, while being redundant from a technical point of view, I personally think it adds clarity, so I would use it as well.

Comment: so I don't need the "this" keyword at all? do my get methods automatically act on the current instance of the class?

Comment: Correct, leave off the "this." prefix and it will use methods and properties of the current instance.

Comment: It's especially good when it comes to code that has exposure to "beginners", as it makes purpose of a statement more explicit.

Comment: The only place you should use this is when you have a private field and a local variable with the same name. Unqualified the compiler will pick the local variable. So the following code needs to qualify one with "this":    name = name;

Comment: What I meant is... the only place it is required to use "this", I agree with personal taste, so I didn't mean "do not use this in any other case".

Comment: that is not the only place this is required.  if you want to return the current object you need to return this a good example of this would be overloading operator= to allow chaining

Comment: Using 'this' here is redundant too, just look at the variable names :-)

Answer (score 6):

Use of the redundant `this.`  is encouraged by the Microsoft coding standards as embodied in the [StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis) tool.

Comment: And it's discouraged by Resharper.

Comment: And it's discouraged by CodeRush. For which I hate it.

Comment: And it's discouraged by IDesign's coding standard: "65. Do not use the this reference unless invoking another constructor from within a constructor".

That's how I use this, and I like R#'s default take on this.

http://idesign.net/idesign/download/IDesign%20CSharp%20Coding%20Standard.zip

Answer (score 6):

You can also to overload math operators, [just like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx):

```
public static ComplexNumber operator +(ComplexNumber c1, ComplexNumber c2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're now learning C# and asking about style, I'm going to show you several things that are wrong with the code you posted along with reasons.

**Edit:** I only responded to this because it looks like you actually working to figure this stuff out. Since that's the type of people I prefer to work with, I'm more critical simply because I hope it helps you get somewhere better as a result. :)

### Structure name

1. `ComplexNumber` is unnecessarily long. Note that none of `Single`, `Double`, `Int32`, `Int64`, etc. have `Number` in the name. This suggests `Complex` as a more appropriate name.
2. `Complex` matches the naming already established in the .NET Framework.

### Real and imaginary components

1. `GetRealPart()` and `GetComplexPart()` should be get-only properties instead of methods.
2. `GetComplexPart()` is misnamed because it is actually returning the *imaginary* part.
3. Since the .NET framework already has a `Complex` structure, you shouldn't reinvent the naming. Therefore, unless you are in a position to redefine Framework conventions, the properties *must* be named `Real` and `Imaginary`.

### Operations

If you look at existing examples like [`System.Windows.Vector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.vector_members(v=VS.90).aspx), you see that math operations are implemented by providing a static method and an operator:

```
public static Point Add(Vector vector, Point point);
public static Point operator+(Vector vector, Point point);
```

Not surprisingly, this convention carried over to the [`System.Numerics.Complex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex(v=VS.100).aspx) structure:

```
public static Complex Add(Complex left, Complex right);
public static Complex operator +(Complex left, Complex right);
```

### Summary

The result is clean, easy to verify, and behaves as everyone expects. The `this` keyword doesn't/can't appear because the methods are static.

```
public static Complex Add(Complex left, Complex right)
{
    return new Complex(left.Real + right.Real, left.Imaginary + right.Imaginary);
}

public static Complex operator +(Complex left, Complex right)
{
    return new Complex(left.Real + right.Real, left.Imaginary + right.Imaginary);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this keyword only for variables and when there's an argument that has the same name as the private variable. i.e.

```
private String firstname;
public SetName(String firstname)
{
    this.firstname = firstname;
}
```

Comment: Conveniently this never happens because member fields always start with `_` while parameter names never start with `_`.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes, it looks correct and easy to read. But isn't this something your TA should answer?

Comment: its extra credit, the TA and professor won't help on extra credit, not even talk to you about it. Which makes sense I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of this keyword seems fine.

Though I believe for a class like Complex you should store the real and complex part as int properties and use them in the method, rather than using the methods GetRealPart() and GetComplexPart()

I would do it this way:

```
    class ComplexNumber
    {
        public int RealPart { get; set; }
        public int ComplexPart { get; set; }

        public ComplexNumber(int real, int complex)
        {
            this.RealPart = real;
            this.ComplexPart = complex;
        }

        public ComplexNumber Add(ComplexNumber c)
        {
            return new ComplexNumber(this.RealPart + c.RealPart, this.ComplexPart + c.ComplexPart);
        }
    }
```

The following is a scenario where this MUST be used, otherwise, the parameter and not the class member is considered for both LHS and RHS of the assignment.

```
public ComplexNumber(int RealPart, int ComplexPart)
        {
            RealPart = RealPart; // class member will not be assigned value of RealPart
            ComplexPart = ComplexPart;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double realPartCaller = this.GetRealPart();
```

Even if you omit `this`  from `GetRealPart()` it should still be okay. But the use of `this` makes it quite easy to read and understand when it comes to maintainer.

```
double realPartCaller = this.GetRealPart(); ==> bit more readable IMHO
double realPartCaller = GetRealPart();
```

Answer (score 0):

I find myself more and more using the `this` keyword for both methods and properties on the current instance, as I feel it increases readability and maintainability. this is especially useful if your class also has static methods and/or properties, on which you of course can not use the `this` keyword, as these are not related to the current instance. By using `this`, you clearly see the difference.

To bring it even further, you should consider using the class name as a qualifier for static methods and properties, even within the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add completeness to the answers - there is one case when the `this` keyword is mandatory. That's when you have a local variable (or a method parameter) that has the same name as a class member. In this case writing it without `this` will access the local variable and with `this` will set the class member. To illustrate:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int SomeVariable;

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        int SomeVariable;

        SomeVariable = 4; // This assigns the local variable.
        this.SomeVariable = 6; // This assigns the class member.
    }
}
```

A couple things that follow from this:

- Always avoid giving local variables the same name as class members (I admit, I don't always follow this myself);
- Writing `this` in front of all member accesses acts like a safeguard. If you write a piece of code without it, and then later introduce a local variable with the same name and type as a class member, your code will still compile just fine, but will do something completely different (and probably wrong).

One instance though where I use the same names for method parameters as for class members is in constructors. I often write it like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int VariableA;
    public string VariableB;

    public MyClass(int VariableA, string VariableB)
    {
        this.VariableA = VariableA;
        this.VariableB = VariableB;
    }
}
```

In my opinion this makes the constructor clearer, because you immediately understand which parameter sets which class member.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the naming conventions, using this is rearlly neded:

```
class MyClass 
{ 
    public int _variableA; 
    public string _variableB; 

    public MyClass(int variableA, string variableB) 
    { 
        _variableA = variableA; 
        _variableB = variableB; 
    } 
}
```